# ダークモードでレビュー内容の初回表示時のアニメーションがライトモードのまま

Tags: バグ, デザイン, ダークモード

#### 不具合事象

ダークモードでレビュー内容の初回表示時のアニメーションがライトモードのものになっています。問題を再現した動画像を撮影出来ていないため、文章で不具合事象の内容を書いておきます。

1. レビュー対象の投稿が表示される
2. 投稿全体の背景が黄色になる
3. 黄色の状態から次第に白色の背景へと遷移していく
4. 完全に白色になった後、透明に戻る

これはライトモードのような白色背景では、投稿が黄色背景で強調された後に次第にもとの背景色へ戻っていく、というアニメーションになります。しかし、ダークモードでは投稿の文字色が白色に近い色になっているため、アニメーションの過程で白色背景になるとテキストが読みにくくなります。また、暗い背景のページで突然白色の背景が出現すると、目が痛くなってしまいます。

Comment: レビューキューのデザインが変わったので、もしかすると再現性が無くなったかもしれません